# Uniqueness of complex tori

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

In the abelian case compact abelian Lie groups  are unique up to  diffeomorphism i.e. $(S^1)^n$.

How about  the complex case? Are complex tori unique up to holomorphism i.e $(T)^n$ where $T=S^1\times S^1$?

Comment: What does "compact abelian Lie groups are unique up to diffeomorphism" mean?

Comment: I mean if $G$ is a compact abelian Lie group of dimension $n$, then $G\cong(S^1)^n$.

Comment: Ah. Probably you should have said that.

Comment: For a lattice $\Lambda_1 = u\Bbb{Z}+v\Bbb{Z}$ then $\Bbb{C}/\Lambda_1\cong \Bbb{C}/\Lambda_2$ iff $\Lambda_1 = c \Lambda_2$, then $\Lambda_1=(au+bv)\Bbb{Z}+(cu+dv)\Bbb{Z}$ for any $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb{Z},ad-bc = \pm 1$. Letting $t = u/v$ we obtain the moduli space of complex tori is $(\Bbb{C-R}) /PGL_2(\Bbb{Z})= \mathcal{H}/SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ the first modular curve https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  There is a one-dimensional moduli of elliptic curves, for example.

Comment: Can you please say more on this example. Thanks!

Comment: See [this](/questions/316181) for example.  For higher dimension you also have complex tori that are nonprojective.